# How to use variable dynamically inside while loop

Tags: ksh, variable

Getting error while executing below in Unix: i want the 3rd line to get work... In ksh shell

```
while [ ${i} -le 3 ]
do
     var${i}="hello${i}"
     echo "${var}${i}"
     i=`expr ${i} + 1`
done
```

I want to get a output like below,

```
hello1
hello2
```

Comment: Which shell do you want to use? Do you want a POSIX compliant solution, or bash or zsh or something else?

Comment: ... what error?

Comment: I want in Ksh shell

Comment: So much easier to use an array than to use dynamic variable names.

Comment: Which `ksh` shell? `ksh88`, `ksh93`, `pdksh` or `mksh`? What does `echo $KSH_VERSION` display?

Comment: @hschou, for a second I thought you were spamming SE with links to porn sites :-) I even flagged it as such. Looks like I can't retract it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In POSIX `sh`, you'd need `eval` to use variables with dynamic names.

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 3 ]
do
   eval '
     var'"$i"'="hello${i}"
     echo "var$i = ${var'"$i"'}"
   '
   i=$((i+1))
done
echo "${var1}"
```

When using `eval`, it's critical to make sure that only the variables that need to be expanded are expanded in the argument passed to `eval` (and that their value be sanitized (here we know they are safe sequences of decimal digits)).

Above only two of the `$i`'s are expanded. To do that, we get out of the single (strong) quotes and insert the `$i` inside double quotes: `eval '...'"$i"'...'`.

Because it's so hard to get the quoting right (and it's dangerous if you don't), it's better to limit the use of `eval` as much as possible. Ideally only to transfer the content of the dynamic variable to a static one and/or back like:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 3 ]
do
   var=hello$i # $var with static name
   eval "var$i=\$var" # transfer into variable with dynamic name

   echo "var$i = $var" # use var with static name instead of dynamic one
                       # everywhere else (for which we don't need eval)

   i=$((i+1))
done
echo "${var2}"
```

In `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`/`yash`, you may want to use arrays instead (or associative arrays in `ksh93`, `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`). Note that `ksh`/`bash` array indices start at `0` and arrays are sparse (more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers) while in all other shells (including `zsh` and `yash` on the Bourne-like front), indices start at 1 and arrays are normal arrays.

In `ksh`/`bash`/`zsh -o ksharrays`:

```
unset -v var
i=0; while [ "$i" -le 3 ]; do
  var[i]=hello$i
  echo "var[$i]=${var[i]}"
  i=$((i+1))
done
echo "${var[1]}"
```

Or using another `((...))` extension of the POSIX `sh` syntax common to `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`:

```
unset -v var
i=0; while ((i <= 3)); do
  var[i]=hello$i
  echo "var[$i]=${var[i]}"
  ((++i))
done
echo "${var[2]}"
```

Or with `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh -o ksharrays`:

```
unset -v var
for ((i = 0; i <= 3; i++)); do
  var[i]=hello$i
  echo "var[$i]=${var[i]}"
done
echo "${var[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's much easier with a `for` loop:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  echo var$i\ =\ hello$i
done
```

Tested in `bash`.

Comment: Actually the main idea is i want assign value to the variable instead of just displaying